# Zip-code in C# and aspx as VarChar and not int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to make zip-code a VarChar in the SQL Database type and have it submit in the database with letters and numbers. When the zip-code has the int SQL Database type the form is submitted into the zip column in the database, but when the value of the zip-code is VarChar 50 the value is not submitted to the new column in the database named zipPostal.

Here is the code in aspx:

```
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="zipLabel" AssociatedControlID="zip">Zip/Postal 
     Code</asp:Label>     
    <asp:TextBox ID="zip" name="zip" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the snippets of the code in C#:

```
    /// Form post data from registration form
    string username = Request.Form["UserName"];
    string first = Request.Form["first"];
    string last = Request.Form["last"];
    string zip = Request.Form["zip"];

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50,  
    ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, emails));

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15,   
    ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, username));

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20,    
    ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, first));

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20,      
    ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, last));


sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, 
    ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, zip));
```

SQL Command type:

```
     int chk = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

     public string CheckEmail(string Email)
     {

     string returnValue = string.Empty;
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
     SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand

     ("CheckEmailAvailability", conn);
     try
     {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = 

     CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", 

     Email.Trim());
        conn.Open();
        returnValue = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();
     }
     catch
     {

     }

     finally
     {
        conn.Close();
        sqlCommand.Dispose();
     }

     return returnValue;
     }
```

////

```
    public string CheckUsername(string Username)
    {

    string returnValue = string.Empty;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand

    ("CheckUsernameAvailability", conn);
    try
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = 

    CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", 

    Username.Trim());
        conn.Open();
        returnValue = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        sqlCommand.Dispose();
    }

    return returnValue;
    }

    }
```

//STORED PROCEDURE

```
   if (username != "")
   {
        string checkUN = CheckUsername(username);

        if (checkUN == "true")
        {
            Label2.Text = "Username already exists.";
            gotoauth = 0;
            return;

        }
    }
    //[ckc] end check username 

    if (password != confirmpwd)
    {
        Label2.Text = "The Password and Confirmation 

   Password must match.";
       gotoauth = 0;
        return;
    }



   //connection with db and call procedure.
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand

    ("customers_insert", conn);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    conn.Open();


    try
    {


    if (gotoauth == 0) 
     {}


    else
        {



var customerGateway = new 

    CustomerGateway(_loginApikey, _TransactionKey, 

    ServiceMode.Live);
    var NewCustomer = customerGateway.CreateCustomer

    (emails, "Live User Account");
    var datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString(); 

string proid = NewCustomer.ProfileID;
    Session["Customerproid"] = proid;
```

/// SQL Procedure

```
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[customers_insert]
    @email varchar(50) ,
    @username varchar(15) ,
    @firstName varchar(20) ,
    @lastName varchar(20) ,
    @country varchar(50) ,
    @address varchar(100) ,
    @city varchar(100) ,
    @state varchar(50) ,
    @account bigint = null ,
    @profileID bigint = null ,
    @password varchar(20) ,
    @customerNumber int = null ,
    @question varchar(50)  ,
    @answer varchar(50) ,
    @dob varchar(50) ,
    @AccountNumber varchar(50) = null ,
    @PinNumber varchar(50) = null ,
    @PhoneNumber varchar(50) = null, 
    @ApprovalID int,
    @DateTime varchar (50) = null,
    @thoughts varchar (100) = null,
    @zip varchar (50) = null


    AS

    INSERT [dbo].[customers]
    (
    [email],
    [username],
    [firstName],
    [lastName],
    [country],
    [address],
    [city],
    [state],
    [account],
    [profileID],
    [password],
    [customerNumber],
    [question],
    [answer],
    [dob],
    [AccountNumber],
    [PinNumber],
    [PhoneNumber],
    [ApprovalID],
    [DateTime],
    [thoughts],
    [zip]


    )
    VALUES
    (
    @email,
    @username,
    @firstName,
    @lastName,
    @country,
    @address,
    @city,
    @state,
    @account,
    @profileID,
    @password,
    @customerNumber,
    @question,
    @answer,
    @dob,
    @AccountNumber,
    @PinNumber,
    @PhoneNumber,
    @ApprovalID,
    @DateTime,
    @thoughts,
    @zip

    )
```

In the SQL Database, there is a column for zip (int, not null) and a column for zipPostal (varChar(50), null). I want the zip-code data to be going in the zipPostal column so it accepts letters and numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a query or a stored procedure? and what does the query or stored procedure look like?

Comment: you can't just expect SQL Server to magically make that determination for you..

Comment: Please show more of your existing code. The "snippets" you've shown above really aren't enough to go on.

Comment: I copy pasted only the zip-code part from aspx and C# file.

Comment: You state you have a `zip (int, not null)` column, but still you try to assign it with a varchar value `SqlDbType.VarChar, 50`. You need to convert it to the correct type (int) before assigning the parameter.

Comment: In SQL Server, I have created a column for zipPostal with the datatype of VarChar (50). I have also created a procedure for this column so it accepts letters, but still get an error when the form is submitted.

Comment: But you didn't paste enough code.  How about the rest of the sqlCommand stuff?

Comment: @TempoNetworks does that procedure point to the correct column? I'm better it doesn't. To know for sure, we'll need to see it.

Comment: @Patrick The zip(int, not null) is the works and the data is being stored in the zip column in the database with the int type. But even when I changed the zip to VarChar (50) it still gives me an error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you post your SQL statement or Procedure code, also post any errors that are thrown

Comment: @TempoNetworks: Please also include the error you get, in your question. "It doesn't work" will not help us help you

Comment: You're still not showing the important part, which is the `sqlCommand` command text.

Comment: Not only is what you posted as the "stored procedure" completely irrelevant, it isn't even a stored procedure - it's C# code.  A stored procedure is SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a query -- either in the back-end database in the form of a stored procedure, or in your c# code in the form of a `SqlCommand` -- that refers to the `zip` column. You'll need to change that query/procedure to refer to the proper field. If your code says the value should be inserted into `zip`, it's never going to be inserted into `zipPostal`.

EDIT: Now that we can see your stored procedure, it confirms that this is the issue. Here's how to fix it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[customers_insert]
@email varchar(50) ,
@username varchar(15) ,
@firstName varchar(20) ,
@lastName varchar(20) ,
@country varchar(50) ,
@address varchar(100) ,
@city varchar(100) ,
@state varchar(50) ,
@account bigint = null ,
@profileID bigint = null ,
@password varchar(20) ,
@customerNumber int = null ,
@question varchar(50)  ,
@answer varchar(50) ,
@dob varchar(50) ,
@AccountNumber varchar(50) = null ,
@PinNumber varchar(50) = null ,
@PhoneNumber varchar(50) = null, 
@ApprovalID int,
@DateTime varchar (50) = null,
@thoughts varchar (100) = null,
@zip varchar (50) = null


AS

INSERT [dbo].[customers]
(
[email],
[username],
[firstName],
[lastName],
[country],
[address],
[city],
[state],
[account],
[profileID],
[password],
[customerNumber],
[question],
[answer],
[dob],
[AccountNumber],
[PinNumber],
[PhoneNumber],
[ApprovalID],
[DateTime],
[thoughts],
[zipPostal] /*Here's what I changed*/


)
VALUES
(
@email,
@username,
@firstName,
@lastName,
@country,
@address,
@city,
@state,
@account,
@profileID,
@password,
@customerNumber,
@question,
@answer,
@dob,
@AccountNumber,
@PinNumber,
@PhoneNumber,
@ApprovalID,
@DateTime,
@thoughts,
@zip

)
```

You could also possibly edit this in a more complicated way to put the zip codes into `Zip` or `zipPostal` depending on its value, but I'd argue that you should put everything into `zipPostal`. You should have all the data in one place, and Zip Code data should always be stored as a string, not a number, as Galactic Cowboy wrote below in a comment.

Comment: I tried rerouting zip to enter zipPostal as a VarChar. This was done by changing what you see up top from zip to zipPostal. The problem is that the field zip won't allow letter to be submitted.

Comment: That's because changing the name of the parameter isn't the important part. You need to change the command text itself. I'm almost positive that the problem is in `sqlCommand.CommandText`; please post that section of your c# code.

Comment: I don't have a commandText, but commandType is in my code which is used to see if the email is already in use.  I will post it up top.

Comment: So how does your c# code know what query to execute? There has to be command text implemented somehow, either as a string in the c# code or as a stored procedure in the backend database. That's where the change needs to be made.

Comment: Please post absolutely everything between `sqlCommand = new SqlCommand()` (there ought to be something like that) and `sqlCommand.Execute()`.

Comment: I have posted most of it on top.

Comment: @TempoNetworks, we need to see your insert/update statement sql code. can you post that?

Comment: It looks like there's a stored procedure that's being called from `sqlCommand`. We need to see the definition of that.

Comment: I have posted under stored procedures.

Comment: Getting closer. You've showed that your c# is calling a procedure called `customers_insert`. Now we need the definition of that procedure from your sql code. I'm sure we'll find that it's pointing to the wrong field.

Comment: If you don't have access to your backend and/or know how to edit it, this is going to be difficult.

Comment: I have access to everything, just stumped in this situation.

Comment: @TempoNetworks I can try to talk you through it in chat. Please click here: [Zip-code in C# and aspx as VarChar and not int](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25972/zip-code-in-c-and-aspx-as-varchar-and-not-int)

Comment: I cannot talk in there since I need 20 rep.

Comment: Ugh. Let's start with this: What back-end database system are you using? Sql Server, MySQL, etc.?

Comment: SQL Server. We can use a different chat system if you would like.

Comment: @TempoNetworks With SQL Server, I think I can get you there fairly quickly. In Sql Server Management Studio, expand your database, the expand `programmability`, then `Stored Procedures`. Find the procedure called `customers_insert` (probably will say `dbo.customers_insert`), right click, and select "Modify." That should display the stored procedure's definition.

Comment: I have done that many times in the past and still the data doesn't enter in the new column. Is there a way I can edit zip column and make it a varChar (50) since I don't see an option for editing the column in the table without dropping the whole table.

Comment: After you get the stored procedure's definition, please post it above so we can fix it.

Comment: There you have it. As I posted above, just change zip to zipPostal in the definition and click Execute in SSMS

Comment: What would my SQL command be?              sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zip",SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, zip));    ??

Comment: Along with my field string zip = Request.Form["zip"];  ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change those at all. Just update the stored procedure and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm very busy at my day job today and won't have time to help on this. My apologies :-)

Comment: That is fine,                                                      Thank you for your help Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted the relevant SQL code.

You have posted code that calls a "CheckUserNameAvailability" stored procedure and another that calls a stored procedure named "CheckEmailAvailability". Neither of these stored procedures seem related to the code that attempts to set the postal code.

I suspect that you are calling another stored procedure that takes @Zip as a parameter. That stored procedure will have to be edited to update the correct column.

UPDATE:

Change

```
INSERT [dbo].[customers]
(
[email],
[username],
[firstName],
[lastName],
[country],
[address],
[city],
[state],
[account],
[profileID],
[password],
[customerNumber],
[question],
[answer],
[dob],
[AccountNumber],
[PinNumber],
[PhoneNumber],
[ApprovalID],
[DateTime],
[thoughts],
[zip]


)
VALUES
(
@email,
@username,
@firstName,
@lastName,
@country,
@address,
@city,
@state,
@account,
@profileID,
@password,
@customerNumber,
@question,
@answer,
@dob,
@AccountNumber,
@PinNumber,
@PhoneNumber,
@ApprovalID,
@DateTime,
@thoughts,
@zip

)
```

to

```
INSERT [dbo].[customers]
(
[email],
[username],
[firstName],
[lastName],
[country],
[address],
[city],
[state],
[account],
[profileID],
[password],
[customerNumber],
[question],
[answer],
[dob],
[AccountNumber],
[PinNumber],
[PhoneNumber],
[ApprovalID],
[DateTime],
[thoughts],
[zipPostal]


)
VALUES
(
@email,
@username,
@firstName,
@lastName,
@country,
@address,
@city,
@state,
@account,
@profileID,
@password,
@customerNumber,
@question,
@answer,
@dob,
@AccountNumber,
@PinNumber,
@PhoneNumber,
@ApprovalID,
@DateTime,
@thoughts,
@zip

)
```

Comment: posted under stored procedure